# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS fails to boot and returns to boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

Every time I try to boot Ubuntu, it goes black screen for like 10-20 seconds, then turns off and goes back to the boot menu (GRUB)

I've tried recovery, which stops at loading initial ramdisk, the nomodeset thing, as well as yannubuntu boot-repair

This is an Asus ROG flow that I have dual booted (and used Ubuntu on) for like half a year, and I don't remember making any major changes before it suddenly stopped working

This is the pastebin that yannubuntu sent after I tried to run it with default settings

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g4VQ4DXp7C/

Edit: I tried to do a full reinstall of Linux, and it was letting me boot in, until I let it install some updates and then it went back to the previous issue.

Comment: Which boot menu? GRUB? Or your BIOS/UEFI? Can you even get to GRUB?

Comment: It says GNU GRUB.

Comment: I've tried to just save important data, format the partition, and reinstall Linux. 
It worked until I let it install some updates, then it just went back to looping grub